# Associating a class with same type

Tags: java

I have a class Student having following properties:

```
public class Student
{
   private int studentId;
   private String studentName;
   private int age;
   List< Student > associatedStudents = new ArrayList<>();

   // Setters and getters here
}
```

And above class have a field `associatedStudents` with type List of same class. My question is: Does `associatedStudents` is a normal type of association or something else ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'normal type of association'?

Comment: No, it's not. Use **sets** for this occasion. One student can be associated to as many other **unique** students.

Comment: @nicomp association means a single student can be associated with multiple students.

Comment: @SudhirOjha is there an abnormal type of association?

Comment: @nicomp no abnormal type of association here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's absolutely normal in Java to have an object contain references to objects of the same class. You can even have a class reference itself.

It's useful for building trees and lists of objects.